# How to insert a listing inside a definition in LyX

Tags: lyx, itemize

My problem is that when I want to insert a list after having inserted a definition, LyX seems to end the `\begin{defn}` block and start the `\begin{itemize}` block. What I want is to have the `\begin{itemize}` block inside the `\begin{defn}` one. How can I do this whithout having to modify tex code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⇾</kbd> to make the new block nested in the current one.

**EDIT** As noted by @scottkosty bellow, <kbd>Tab</kbd> works also

[image]

Comment: tab should work also. And note to get out of the nesting just press return a few times.